# str_replace() in php only replacing the last element of the argument array if the array is created from .txt file

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace, explode, fread

I am making a *Chat Room Application* in which I am trying to make a program in PHP which will replace the text inputs like 
 `:smile:`,`:cry:`, `:sad:` etc into their respective emojis.

For this purpose, I am using `str_replace()` function in PHP which takes three arguments 
1. Text to be replaced, 
2.Replace with 
3. String on which replace needs to be performed.

Like this:
 `str_replace($need_to_replace,$to_be_replaced_with,$string);`

`$need_to_replace` and `$to_be_replaced_with` can be either just simple string or it can be even array.

In my case, I am using array. When I am using array which I am creating like this: `$need_to_replace=[':smile:',':cry:',':happy:'];` and `$to_be_replaced_with=['smile_emoji','cry_emoji','happy_emoji']`
then code is working perfectly fine and replace is working fine like this:

```
   :smile: -> smile_emoji
   :cry:   -> cry_emoji
   :happy: -> happy_emoji
```

But now I am taking `emoji_code.txt` file using PHP and then I am converting the emoji codes from that **.txt** file into an array and assigning that array variable name of `$need_to_replace`. Similarly, I am reading  `emoji_item.txt` file and converting texts from that file into an array and assigning that array as `$to_be_replaced_with`. Now, In this case, it is only replacing the last element of the array `$need_to_replace` with the respective last `$to_be_replaced_with` array.

**For example:** 
           `:happy:` -> `happy_emoji`

**MAIN PROBLEM:**
 Leaving `:smile:` and `:cry:` as it is without replacing them with `smile_emoji` and `cry_emoji` respectively.

This code I am using to convert words in emoji_code.txt into arrays and respectively similar code for emoji_items.txt :

```
//make an array from file emoji_code.txt   
   $file="emoji_code.txt";

    $fopen = fopen($file, 'r');

    $fread = fread($fopen,filesize($file));

    fclose($fopen);

    $remove = "\n";

//$need_to_replace is the array generated from the file **emoji_item.txt**
    $need_to_replace = explode($remove, $fread);
```

**emoji_code.txt** file contains words in this way just texts in a new line (same for **emoji_item.txt** too):

**emoji_code.txt**

```
:smile:
:cry:
:happy:
```

**emoji_item.txt**

```
smile_emoji
cry_emoji
happy_emoji
```

Also, I did a test to compare the self-written array with the array generated by reading the .txt file with the same elements inside. But on comparing I got result `FALSE`

I used `print_r()` to see the contents of both the array and I got this:

```
Array ( [0] => :smile: [1] => :cry: [2] => :happy: ) 
Array ( [0] => :smile: [1] => :cry: [2] => :happy: )
```

Both the arrays have same data.

Comment: Are you sure your `$to_be_replaced_with` array is being read from the correct file? Also, why are you opening/reading/exploding yourself when you can just use `$need_to_replace = file("emoji_code.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);`?

Comment: the line breaks are correct `\n` vs `\n\r` ?

Comment: `file("emoji_code.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);` is working but why this particular method is not working even if it is giving the same array? @rickdenhaan

Comment: Try `var_dump()` instead of `print_r()`. If your text files were created on Windows, your lines may end with `\r\n`. Since you're `explode`'ing on `\n` only, your array may still have the `\r` in the values (`print_r()` does not display these).

Comment: @ rickdenhaan thanks man that worked!! I replaced `\n` with `\r\n` and it worked. Earlier I tried replacing `\n` with `\n\r` but it was not working because it had to be `\r\n`

Comment: Actually, I want to replace `:smile:` with something like `<img src='smile.png'></img>` and `smile.png` I am storing in .txt file. Is there any way to do this without writing `<img src=' '></img>` in the emoji_item.txt for each elements?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. I've added an answer that shows how to do that.

Comment: Awsm!! That worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> *Actually, I want to replace `:smile:` with something like `<img src='smile.png'></img>` and `smile.png` I am storing in .txt file. Is there any way to do this without writing `<img src=' '></img>` in the emoji_item.txt for each elements?*

Yes, although it's slightly more convoluted than simply using `str_replace`. You can do this using `preg_replace_callback`.

The first step is to transform your array of search strings into an array of regular expressions:

```
$expressions_need_to_replace = array_map(
    function($placeholder) {
        return '/' . $placeholder . '/';
    },
    $need_to_replace
);
```

> This is because the expression needs to begin and end with the same character. Your original strings already do this (they begin and end with `:`) but that means they'll actually match `"smile"` instead of `":smile:"` so we need to put a different character at the beginning and end. Make sure you use a character that is not used anywhere in one of the placeholder strings, so if you have a string you want to match like `":in/out:"` use something else, like `return '#' . $placeholder . '#';` -- or, alternatively, use `preg_quote()` like this: `return '/' . preg_quote($placeholder, '/') . '/';`

Now we can search for those expressions and pass all matches through a function that will build an image tag:

```
$input_text = 'This is a :happy: text containing a :smile:, another :smile: but also a :cry:.';

$output_text = preg_replace_callback(
    $expressions_need_to_replace,
    function($match) use ($need_to_replace, $to_be_replaced_with) {
        // first find out where in  $need_to_replace  the found match is
        $index = array_search($match[0], $need_to_replace);

        // get the image from the same location in  $to_be_replaced_with
        $image = $to_be_replaced_with[$index];

        // build the image string
        return '<img src="' . $image . '" />';
    },
    $input_text
);

echo $output_text;
// This is a <img src="happy.png" /> text containing a <img src="smile.png" />, another <img src="smile.png" /> but also a <img src="cry.png" />.
```

Working example: https://3v4l.org/vAX8H